# How to get localized prices with cordova-plugin-purchase

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-purchase

In my app, created with Cordova, I would like to do IAP and show prices with local currency.

To do that I used this plugin: https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase

On the documentation I have:

> When you perform the initial refresh() call, the store's server will be contacted to load informations about the registered products: human readable title and description, price, etc.

But when I execute the following code I have the product but the price is set to "null"

```
store.verbosity = store.DEBUG;
store.ready(function() {
      store.refresh();
      alert("Object:"+ store.get(PREMIUM_PACK_ID));
      alert("Price:"+ store.get(PREMIUM_PACK_ID).price);
 });
for (var i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++){
      var params = this.products[i];
      store.register({
         id:    params.id,
         alias: params.label,
         type:  params.type || store.CONSUMABLE
      });
}
store.refresh();
```

**Some informations:**

- CLI 5.2
- Android 5
- App in closed Beta-test mode
- PREMIUM_PACK_ID === product ID on store
- Refresh & ready well executed
- Tried with one or two refresh...

Does anyone success to get the IAP prices with this plugin?

I try to post here before open an issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally use this other IAP plugin: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-wizPurchase

Works on IOS & Android.